# UglifyJS2 , -m sort option does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to minifier a simple javascript code with [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), but also by including the -[m sort](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options) in the command, the variables are not changed

### Mangler , sort options

> sort — to assign shorter names to most frequently used variables. This
>   saves a few hundred bytes on jQuery before gzip, but the output is
>   bigger after gzip (and seems to happen for other libraries I tried it
>   on) therefore it's not enabled by default.

This is the command that I use

```
uglifyjs jsfile.js -m sort -c -o jsfile.min.js
```

This is the jsfile.js

```
var ciao_ciao = 10;

ciao_ciao++;

function ciao_come_va(){


}

ciao_come_va();
```

This is the jsfile.min.js

```
function ciao_come_va(){}var ciao_ciao=10;ciao_ciao++,ciao_come_va();
```

As you can see the name of variables and functions is not changed

Answer (score 0):

Your function and variables will not be mangled because they are in the global scope.

If you wrap your code (as below), the function and variables will be mangled.

```
(function(){

    var ciao_ciao = 10;

    ciao_ciao++;

    function ciao_come_va(){

    }

    ciao_come_va();

})
```